# Does Visual Studio 2017 Community create a Services folder for Dependency Injection with Core 1.0?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

If I use VS 2015 Community and create a new Project for 4.5.2, MVC, I get the Services folder for DI.  If I install the Core 1.0 with 2017, I don't.  It looks like MVC, but it is missing things.  I know it is a Release Candidate, and I know that 4.5.2 and VS 2015 are mature, but Core 1.0 is supposed to have Dependency Injection built in.

Do I need to install something else?

Comment: Why doesn't it create it?

Comment: I looked at my old project, which I created in VS 2015 and see this Services folder. Let me check for VS 2017 when I come home.

Comment: No rush.  Still in the understanding mode.

Comment: yes, I have Services folder in VS 2017, it has 3 files: IEmailSender.cs, ISmsSender.cs, MessageServices.cs, the same as in VS 2015. Did you select Authentication, when you created project?

Comment: yes, just created ASP.NET Core project without Authentication and it doesn't have Services folder, because this folder originally contains files, related to accounts.

Comment: so, result: Services folder created if you have something to put into it.

Comment: can you check from your side if you have Services folder if created project with Authentication?